# Inheritance of modules in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

What is the purpose of a class inheriting directly from a module? I understand the use of the inheritance but I do not understand how to use the inheritances of modules. For a long time I have seen examples like the following:

```
class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Posicionar elementos en Tcl/Tk")

        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Hola, mundo!")
        self.button.pack()

        self.pack()
```

or also the following example

```
class Hilo_test(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        contador = 1 
        while contador <= 5:
            print('ejecutando',
                  threading.current_thread().getName(), "Contando: 
"+str(contador))
            contador += 1
        print(' FINALIZANDO HILO: {} >>'.format(self.getName()))
```

In these examples the classes inherit from ttk.Frame and threading.Thread.
I do not understand how this works or for what cases it could be useful to inherit directly from the module and its class. Could someone give me a simple example of its use and operation?

Comment: Those aren't modules.

Answer (score 6):

They are not inheriting from modules, but from classes.

Consider the following situation.

**File my_module.py**

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass
```

**File test.py**

```
import my_module 

class TestClass(my_module.MyClass):
    pass
```

TestClass is inheriting from `MyClass` taken from the module `my_module`.

This corresponds also to:

```
from my_module import MyClass

class TestClass(MyClass):
    pass
```

Comment: I'd add: _separation of concerns_, when structuring a project, you may want to have that in mind.

Comment: I understand that the purpose is to use classes from the inherited module, but my concern is that first I do not understand the purpose since the module can be used in importing it without needing to inherit it. what is the utility? ..

Comment: You are not inheriting from a module, you are inheriting from a class in a module. In your example, from the class `Thread` in the module `threading`.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of inheritance is that a subclass can inherit methods and attributes from the superclass.  For example, I have this code:

```
class Superclass():
    def print_hello(self):
        print('hello')

    def count_to_five(self):
        for number in range(1, 6):
            print(str(number))

class Subclass(Superclass):
    pass

instance = Subclass()
instance.print_hello()
instance.count_to_five()
```

This program outputs:

```
hello
1
2
3
4
5
```

Since Subclass inherits methods from Superclass, even though no methods are defined in Subclass, an instance of Subclass can call methods which it inherits from Superclass.  In a nutshell, that is why inheritance is useful.

In your case, `Application` inherits all of `ttk.Frame`’s attributes.  This means that you can access all of `ttk.Frame`’s attributes without having to manually define them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ttk
class Application(ttk.Frame):
    pass
```

is the same as

```
from ttk import Frame
class Application(ttk.Frame):
    pass
```

You are not using the module directly, you are still using the class `Frame` defined in `ttk`, just in different syntax.